# Mudblazor datagrid rows not selecting with RowClassFunc

Tags: c#, blazor, mudblazor

I am working with server side paging and filtering for a mudblazor datagrid, and upon checking a row, everything saves properly, but I cannot get the rows to recheck on page change, with the RowClassFunc.

I tried creating a RowClassFunc applying the class "selected" according to others who have had success, but it is not working.

```
<MudDataGrid 
            T="ObservationListModel" 
            MultiSelection="@true" 
            @ref="_dataGrid" 
            @bind-SelectedItems="selectedItems" 
            ServerData="LoadGridData" 
            SortMode="SortMode.Multiple" 
            Filterable="true"
            RowClassFunc="SelectedRowClassFunc"
            Hideable="false" 
            Elevation="5" 
            Dense="@true">
            <ToolBarContent>
                <MudSpacer />
                <MudTextField T="string" Value="@_requestDto.Search" Placeholder="Search" Adornment="Adornment.Start" Immediate="false"
                              AdornmentIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Search" IconSize="Size.Medium" Class="mt-0" ValueChanged="OnSearchChange"></MudTextField>
            </ToolBarContent>
            <Columns>
                <SelectColumn T="ObservationListModel" />
                <TemplateColumn Sortable="@false" Filterable="@false" Title="Detail" >
                    <CellTemplate>
                        <MudStack Row>
                            <MudButton Size="@Size.Small" Variant="@Variant.Filled" Href="@($"obsdetail/{context.Item.ReferenceID}/{context.Item.OriginalDataID}")" Color="@Color.Primary">View</MudButton>
                        </MudStack>
                    </CellTemplate>
                </TemplateColumn>
                <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.ScientificName" Title="Scientific Name" Sortable="true" />
                <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.ObservationDate" Title="Observation Date" Sortable="true" Filterable="false" />
                <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Class" Title="Class" Sortable="true"/>
                <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.CountyName" Title="County" Sortable="true" />
                <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Observer" Title="Observer" Sortable="true" />
                <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.ReviewStatus" Title="Review Status" Sortable="true" />
            </Columns>
            <PagerContent>
                <MudText>@($"{selectedItems.Count} items selected")</MudText>
                <MudDataGridPager T="ObservationListModel"/>
            </PagerContent>
        </MudDataGrid>
```

```
@code {

    private MudDataGrid<ObservationListModel>? _dataGrid;
    private ObsRequestModel _requestDto = new();
    private HashSet<ObservationListModel> selectedItems { get; set; } = new HashSet<ObservationListModel>();

    private async Task Search()
    {
        if (_dataGrid is not null)
        {
            await _dataGrid!.ReloadServerData();
        }
    }

    private async Task OnSearchChange(string newValue)
    {
        _requestDto.Search = newValue;
        await Search();
    }

    private async Task<GridData<ObservationListModel>> LoadGridData(GridState<ObservationListModel> state)
    {
        _requestDto.Filters.Clear();
        _requestDto.Page = state.Page + 1;
        _requestDto.PageSize = state.PageSize;

        // Extract sorting information
        var sorting = state.SortDefinitions.FirstOrDefault(); // Assuming single column sorting
        if (sorting != null)
        {
            _requestDto.SortColumn = sorting.SortBy;
            _requestDto.SortDirection = sorting.Descending == false ? "asc" : "desc"; // Convert Enum to string or appropriate format
        }

        // Extract filtering information
        foreach (var filter in state.FilterDefinitions)
        {
            if (filter.Value != null) {

                var colString = filter.Title.ToString();
                var valString = colString == "County" ? await ReferenceService.GetCountyFips(filter.Value.ToString()) : filter.Value.ToString();

                _requestDto.Filters.Add(new FilterDefinition
                {
                    Column = colString,
                    Operator = filter.Operator.ToString(),
                    Value = valString
                });
            } 
            else if (filter.Operator.ToLower() == "is empty" || filter.Operator.ToLower() == "is not empty")
            {
                _requestDto.Filters.Add(new FilterDefinition
                {
                    Column = filter.Title.ToString(),
                    Operator = filter.Operator.ToString(),
                    Value = "0", // Assuming the value is a string, adjust as necessary
                });
            } 

        }

        ObListDTO Response = await ReferenceService.GetAllObs(_requestDto);
        GridData<ObservationListModel> data = new()
        {
            Items = Response.Items,
            TotalItems = Response.ItemTotalCount
        };

        return data;
    }

    private async Task OnStartDateChanged(DateTime? newDate)
    {
        _requestDto.StartDate = newDate;
        await DateChange();
    }

    private async Task OnEndDateChanged(DateTime? newDate)
    {
        _requestDto.EndDate = newDate;
        await DateChange();
    }

    private async Task DateChange()
    {
        if (_dataGrid is not null)
        {
            await _dataGrid!.ReloadServerData();
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        
    }

    private string SelectedRowClassFunc(ObservationListModel element, int rowNumber)
    {
        return selectedItems.Contains(element) ? "selected" : string.Empty;
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean by *page change*?

Comment: if you mean the DataGrid's pager then that's working as expected, demo: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/wkweaFEiTSIyUPoR

Comment: I meant when changing the grid page. For Example, If I select a row, change the page of the grid, then go back, the previously selected rows aren't "selecting".